# SP Org browser - allow users to change their manager

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, organization-browser

To start off with my knowledge of SP and 365 is barely at novice level so please type slowly. :)

We want to use the SP standard org browser web part to show who is where in the company. However instead of using people for the managers we will be using current projects - so it's less of an org chart and more a project chart.

I know that this web part pulls information from our office 365 profiles and would like to know if there is a way to allow the user to change their current manager/project from their profile but only allow them to select certain managers/project, ideally a drop down menu with the appropriate values.

The most important requirement is that it is the user who updates themselves. Any ideas or perhaps another webpart are welcome.

thanks,

Andy